# How to Specify for XCode to Execute Specific Lines of Code or Not Depending Upon Profile

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cocoa-touch

I tried to get my head around schemes, configurations, entitlements and what not and all Iam right now is a mighty confused fellow.

We have 3 people working on an iOS application. I am working on connecting the application to a remote server which is giving out a lot of errors and so when I actually commit the progress, everyone's copy of the application gets the problem. I want to make a kind of profile that I can use so that the other folks can skip the lines of code when they run XCode with their profile.

Is there any way this can be done?

**EDIT:** I think I am looking for Preprocessor Macros to define a condition. I want to do a

```
#if Value = Local
//get data locally
#if Value = Remote
//get data from server
```

How do I so this? Also, how do I assign this "value" a value.

Comment: you can use pre-processors, but not sure what exactly your requirement is.

Comment: I want to be able to add certain conditions to my code so that a certain line of code executes only when a certain profile is set. For example, I want to put something like this. if(profile is debug) {run from server} else {run from local data}

Comment: you can set up a local database and server on each system. Once all work is done, commit to the main file/database/server/etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please see the revised question.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to solve the wrong problem.  If you've got a work-in-progress, you shouldn't be trying to conditionally execute certain lines of code depending on who builds it, you should contain your work-in-progress to a feature branch.  This is not an issue that should be solved during execution, this is a collaboration issue that should be solved with source control.

Comment: The connection of program to the database is a long and app-wide task with snippets going about in every class. I just want to put conditions so that till the time I am done with the remote connection implementation completely, no one's copy tries to get data from remote server. We are using SCM already and that's why it's all the more necessary to not make others' work put to a halt because of my work in progress.

Comment: Yes, I know you want to "just put conditions", and as I said in my answer, this is a poor approach and you should not do that, this is one of the things source control was designed to manage.  Stop committing incomplete things to the main development branch everybody pulls from, and commit to a feature branch until it's ready for others to receive it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is a little more complex. I am also working on other modules of the programs and that's why it'll get very tiring to have to manage all of this. Please see the revised question.. I think Preprocessor Macros is the answer to this problem.

Comment: My answer remains the same - this is a problem you should be solving with proper use of source control.  If you are working on other modules, this is even more essential.

Answer (score 0):

As per your edit, you can convert this idea to

```
#if Value = Local
//get data locally
#if Value = Remote
//get data from server
```

Implement above as:

```
#ifdef LOCAL_DB
//get data locally
#else
//get data from server
#endif
```